# How to init an array with all files in a group in XCode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios

I have a group/folder in my XCode iOS project that has a lot of small sound files, and I don't want to have to type all of them out individually to get them into an array, so is there a way to do it?  With bundles or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at NSBundle's -pathsForResourcesOfType:inDirectory: method.